# SPServices GetListItems GroupBy

Tags: 2013, javascript, caml-query, rest, spservices

I am using the **SPService**, 
the method *GetListItems*. 
I need to **groupBy** the result (distinct). 
This is my code:

```
var CamlQuery = '<Query><GroupBy Collapse="TRUE"><FieldRef Name="nameA" /></GroupBy></Query>';
var CamlViewFields='<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="nameA" /></ViewFields>';

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    webURL: siteURL,
    //CAMLRowLimit: "10",
    listName: "myLists",
    CAMLViewFields: CamlViewFields,
    CAMLQuery: CamlQuery,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) 
    {      
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

but it is not working.
I am using the right [GroupBy Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms415157(v=office.15).aspx) as described on *msdn*.
Is there a way to do the GroupBy using the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding grouping in SharePoint REST, according to [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx), `Grouping` is **not** supported.

One of the solution, is to apply grouping for the JSON results returned from REST endpoint.

### Example

Suppose the following function for getting list items via SharePoint REST API:

```
function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data.d); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you could filter unique values from JSON array as demonstrated in answer [Get unique results from JSON array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680842/1375553):

```
function groupBy(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
       if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result)==-1) {
          result.push(item[propertyName]);
       }
    });
    return result;
}
```

The usage

```
getListItems('https://tenant.sharepoint.com/project','Tasks','?select=Title',
    function(items){    
       var taskNames = groupBy(items,'Title');
       console.log(taskNames);
    },
    function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```